# ERROR: Installing a Fortran library on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fortran, gfortran

I have been trying to install the library with a Makefile written in Fortran using the latest gfortran version.

The instructions are:

> M-LIB is provided with a very bare-bones makefile, which should be
> modified for your Fortran compiler. To compile, run make in the src
> directory. This creates library lib.a and executable m-lib.

The Makefile is:

```
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -O3 
AR = ar
ARFLAGS = -cru
LDFLAGS = 
LIBRARY = lib.a
PROGRAM = m-lib
PROGOBJECTS = LIBTEST.o EOS.o
LIBOBJECTS = ADATA.o \
    ADEBY.o \
    AE2PH.o \
    AEHPP.o \
    AEI3.o \
    AZRTR.o

%.o: %.f
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLAGS) $<

default: $(PROGRAM)

$(LIBRARY): $(LIBOBJECTS) 
    rm -f $(LIBRARY)
    $(AR) -cr $(LIBRARY) $(LIBOBJECTS)

$(PROGRAM): $(PROGOBJECTS) $(LIBRARY)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM) $(PROGOBJECTS) $(LIBRARY)

install:
    cp ../input/q_.input ../example/m-lib.INPUT
    cp ./m-lib ../example/m-lib

clean:
    rm -f $(LIBOBJECTS) $(PROGOBJECTS)

allclean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(LIBRARY)
    make clean
```

And I get this error:

```
enter codegfortran -c -O3  LIBTEST.f
LIBTEST.f:36.26:

  allocate (character(arglen) :: arg)                               
                      1
Error: Variable 'arglen' cannot appear in the expression at (1)
LIBTEST.f:99.72:

  DO 10 I=1,NDENS                                                   
                                                                    1
Warning: DO loop at (1) will be executed zero times
LIBTEST.f:104.72:

  DO 20 J=1,NTEMP                                                   
                                                                    1
Warning: DO loop at (1) will be executed zero times
make: *** [LIBTEST.o] Error 1
```

¿Any idea what is wrong?

EDIT
This is source code of EOS.o:

```
      SUBROUTINE EOS(TEMP,TEMP0,P,RHO,E,M)

      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      TEMP=TEMP0
      IT=0
 10   CONTINUE
      IT=IT+1
      IF(IT.GT.50) STOP 'TOO MANY ITERATIONS--EOS'
      CALL ADEBY (TEMP,RHO,P,ETRIAL,S,CV,DPDT,DPDR,FKROS,CS,KPA,M)
      IF (ABS(E-ETRIAL) .LT. 1.0D-9*E) RETURN
      TEMP=TEMP+(E-ETRIAL)/CV
      GOTO 10
      END
```

This is first lines of the source code of LIBTEST.o:

```
      PROGRAM LIBTEST

      IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
      INTEGER STYLE
      PARAMETER (NDENS=0)
      PARAMETER (NTEMP=0)
      DIMENSION IZETL(21)
      COMMON /FILEOS/ KLST, KINP
      COMMON /ANGELX/ W,Y,ALFA,BETA,DADT,DADR,DBDT,ZZ,ET,
     & SN,CVN,EN,PN,PM,EM,SM,CVM,EC,PC,RHO0,RHO00,ZVIB,
     & SMLT,CVMLT,EMLT,PMLT,H1,H2
      COMMON /ANEEL/ TEVX,RHOX,ABARX,ZBARM,T32X,FNX
     &  ,PE,EE,SE,CVE,DPTE,DPRE
     &  ,NMATSX,IIZX
      COMMON /ANEDIS/ GAMMA,PSI,THETA
      PARAMETER (MATBUF=64)
      COMMON /ANESQT/ SQTS(MATBUF),IPSQTS
      DIMENSION RHO(NDENS),TEMP(NTEMP),HISTDENS(100),HISTPRESS(100)
      DIMENSION HISTDPDR(100)
      DIMENSION TARR(2000)
      DIMENSION DARR(2000)
      DIMENSION PARR(2000,2000)
      DIMENSION SARR(2000,2000)
      DIMENSION EARR(2000,2000)
      DIMENSION CSARR(2000,2000)
      DIMENSION CVARR(2000,2000)
      DIMENSION ZKARR(2000,2000)
C
CSTS ADDS --help, --no_table, and file checks
      character(:), allocatable :: arg
      integer arglen, stat
      logical file_exists
      call get_command_argument(number=1, length=arglen)  ! Assume for simplicity success
      allocate (character(arglen) :: arg)
      call get_command_argument(number=1, value=arg, status=stat)
      IF (arg.NE.'--quiet') THEN
         write(*,9020)
         write(*,9021)
         write(*,9022)
         write(*,9023)
```

(...)

Comment: Are you using a compiler which supports this feature introduced in Fortran 2003?  Although you've tagged as F90, the error relates to something that is not in F90.  That is, what version of gfortran are you trying to use?

Comment: Since the error reported is a *compilation* error it would be necessary to see the source code.  It's not clear that the Makefile you show us is relevant at all.  A wild guess: you have not written `implicit none` in your source code, and Fortran thinks `arglen` is  real variable, not valid for defining the length of a character variable.

Comment: I am using GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: I added the source code. (sorry for the wrong tag)